Redis querying to get values using a wild cards
So im using redis template with spring and saving some data in redis
like so:
this.redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("cars:toyota:corolla",
                car, Duration.ofSeconds(48*60*60);

this.redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("cars:bmw:m3",
                car, Duration.ofSeconds(48*60*60);

I want to be able to retrieve the cars for toyota and bmw and do something like, but i cant get to to work, i have tried the below combinations. All I get back is null.
this.redisTemplate.opsForHash().get("cars:bmw:m3");

redisTemplate.opsForSet().members("cars:*"); // returns empty

I have tried the following to test it
        Boolean b4 = this.redisTemplate.opsForValue().setIfAbsent("ABCD:1",
                        Car.builder().id("test").build(), Duration.ofSeconds(48 * 60 * 60));
    
       Boolean b14 = this.redisTemplate.hasKey("ABCD:1"); // returns true


      Object car = redisTemplate.opsForHash().get("ABCD", "1"); // returns null

my config
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(final RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
    final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
    template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    return template;
}


redisTemplate.opsForSet().members.This is the syntax of 'set' rather than the syntax of 'str'.
redisTemplate.opsForHash().get.This syntax does not support fuzzy matching.
